# How to Check/Uncheck single radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
$('.ssn_byphone').click(function(){
    var ssn_role = document.getElementById('ssn_byphone').checked;                     
    if(ssn_role==true)
    {
        $('#ssn-div').hide();
        $('.ssn_byphone').css('display','block');
        $('#ssn').val('');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#slideUp').show();
    }
});

<input id="ssn_byphone" class="ssn_byphone" type="radio" name="pi[ssn_byphone]" value="Yes"><label for="radio1"> I will provide SSN by phone</label>
```

I want to check/uncheck this radio button when i clicked on it, and want to set condition accordingly.

Comment: use checkbox for this

Comment: No, My design pattern needs radio button.

Comment: To uncheck `radio`, you need to create another radio with value `no`, better use `checkbox` as @guradio recommended

Comment: but radio buttons dont have the checked- unchecked function

Comment: but after creating another radio button it will show on screen, and i want to show just one radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var checked=false;
$('.ssn_byphone').click(function(){
    checked=!checked;
    $(this).prop("checked",checked);
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#ssn-div').hide();
        $('.ssn_byphone').css('display','block');
        $('#ssn').val('');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#slideUp').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ssn_byphone" class="ssn_byphone" type="radio" name="pi[ssn_byphone]" value="Yes"><label for="radio1"> I will provide SSN by phone</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place a checkbox instead of the radio button and change the appearance so that it will look like a radio button

```html
<input id="ssn_byphone" class="ssn_byphone" type="checkbox" name="pi[ssn_byphone]" value="Yes" style="-webkit-appearance: radio; -moz-appearance: radio;-ms-appearance: radio;"><label for="radio1"> I will provide SSN by phone</label>
```

Comment: Better solution, but I still recommend to use `checkbox`

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK AND UNCHECK SINGLE RADIO BUTTON**

```js
  
var myRadio = document.getElementById('ssn_byphone');
var booRadio;

myRadio.onclick = function(){

    if(booRadio == this){
        this.checked = false;
        booRadio = null;
    }else{
        booRadio = this;
    }
};
```

```html
<input id="ssn_byphone" class="ssn_byphone" type="radio" name="pi[ssn_byphone]" value="Yes"><label for="radio1"> I will provide SSN by phone</label>
```