# Radio button check and uncheck onclick and send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I'm trying to send data onclick via ajax with a radio button. If the radio button is clicked and checked, value of 1 is set in the database. If the radio button is already checked, but clicked to uncheck it, the value of 0 is sent to the database. The code I'm using sends the value onclick and checks the radio button but does not uncheck and hence does not send the value to the database. Please help.

```html
<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="'. $row["id"].'">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');

        if (checked != 'checked') {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                 url:"updateaddress.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{home:"1",id:id,},
            });
        } else if (checked == 'checked') {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                 url:"updateaddress.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{home:"0",id:id,},
        });

        }
    });                           
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use ```checkbox``` instead of radio button

Comment: What is in `print_r($_POST);`? There is your value? If yes, than something with *storing to database* logic.

Comment: you need to use `checkbox` either you need to have more then one radio button.

Comment: Also `if ($(this).is(":checked")` or  `if (this.checked)` is simpler than looking at the prop

Comment: Also DRY: Just have ONE `$.ajax({
                 url:"updateaddress.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{home:this.value,id:this.id,},`

Comment: The important thing is supported snippet editor is just for run JS based code it's not able to understand your name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="'. $row["id"].'" radio button. Make sure you write proper value or string in that position

Comment: @DilipBorad nor the Ajax.

Comment: @anthony please check this url :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212483/how-to-check-uncheck-single-radio-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox and

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function(){ 
  $.post("updateaddress.php",{home:this.checked,id:this.id});
});
```

is all you need

If you MUST use a radio, have a look at this

[How to Check/Uncheck single radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212483/how-to-check-uncheck-single-radio-button)

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("click", function(){ 
  $.post("updateaddress.php",{home:this.checked,id:this.id});
  this.checked=!this.checked;
});
```

Comment: So I tried this: $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function(){ 
  $.post("updateaddress.php",{home:this.checked,id:this.id});
});  also works and have to admit, I do love the simplicity of the code. Thanks to you to @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are used when there is multiple options and user should check only one option.so,user can't uncheck a radio button when already checked.you explicitly make a onclick listener and change the radio button status.but it's not advisable.you can use checkbox  for this purpose with onchange event.

```
$(checkEle).on("change",function(){
  var status = $(this).prop("checked");
  sendStatus(status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="'. $row["id"].'">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var data = {home:"0",id:$(this).attr("id")};
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            data = {home:"1",id:$(this).attr("id")};
        }
         $.ajax({
                 url:"updateaddress.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:data,
         });

    });                           
});
</script>
```

You can use this script.Just check if radio button is checked or not and send your values accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by repeat myself? @mplungjan

Comment: Just have ONE `$.ajax({
                 url:"updateaddress.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{home:this.value,id:this.id,},`

Comment: Updated my answer. @mplungjan

Comment: You are still repeating yourself. Why have data defined TWICE - have a look at how simple it can be:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49484822/295783

Comment: Thanks all for help. I went with @SmitRaval as it was the easiest for me to implement. I went with checkboxes as recommended. Works as hoped!

Comment: Very inelegant. `$('input[type="radio"]').on("click", function(){ 
  $.post("updateaddress.php",{home:this.checked,id:this.id});
});` is all you need as I point out in my answer - The answer above does NOT uncheck the radio

Comment: how about the ajax though?

Comment: $.post IS an ajax call